# temporal disaggregation time series using regression

Tags: r, regression, time-series, disaggregation

I originally posted this question on stackoverflow and was recommended to post here instead.

I am trying to derive high frequency data from low frequency data. I also have a number of other related datasets at this higher frequency that I am trying to use to assist with the temporal disaggregation. I am not sure what the best way to approach this is!

For example:

Suppose you are trying to convert from: annual volume of gas used (for heating) to monthly volume of gas used.

You also have temperature, population, etc. on a monthly level. You know that there will be a relationship between these independent variables and the dependent variable that you are trying to estimate at a higher frequency (monthly volume of gas used).

Does anyone know the best approach here? For example, can you average/aggregate your independent variables to the lower frequency (say annual level), perform a regression, and then reduce the dependent variable to the higher frequency subject to this relationship ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many traditional statistical approaches here, and none are a silver bullet for every circumstance. Sax and Steiner (2013; [PDF link](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013/RJ-2013-028/RJ-2013-028.pdf)) collect several methods in the R package [tempdisagg](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013/RJ-2013-028/RJ-2013-028.pdf), namely Denton, Denton-Cholette, Chow-Lin, Fernandez and Litterman.

> [...] On the one hand, Denton (Denton, 1971) and Denton-Cholette (e.g. Dagum and Cholette, 2006) are primarily
>   concerned with movement preservation, generating a series that is similar to the indicator series
>   whether or not the indicator is correlated with the low frequency series. Alternatively, these methods
>   can disaggregate a series without an indicator. On the other hand, Chow-Lin, Fernandez and Litterman
>   use one or several indicators and perform a regression on the low frequency series. Chow-Lin (Chow
>   and Lin, 1971) is suited for stationary or cointegrated series, while Fernandez (Fernández, 1981) and
>   Litterman (Litterman, 1983) deal with non-cointegrated series.

Also see Montazerin and Zarandi (2015, [abstract](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7329985)) which discusses temporal disaggregation of natural gas time series specifically.